# Как правильно расставить знаки при прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Есть диалог, который понятно как записать при помощи кавычек:

```
Когда старца спрашивали: «Как дела?», он отвечал: «Слава Богу за всё!»
```

Теперь представьте, что вопрос и ответ длиннее, или что дальше диалог продолжается, и хочется записать фразы на отдельных строках, начинающихся с тире. Как в таком случае правильно оформить пунктуацию?

```
Когда старца спрашивали: 
– Как дела? — он отвечал: 
— Слава Богу за всё!
— Богу-то слава, дела-то как? — спрашивали его снова.
```

Это «он отвечал», висящее на предыдущей строке, меня смущает.

Comment: Вас смущает запятая?

Comment: @Серж Меня смущает вторая строка в диалоге: получается строка, состоящая из прямой речи одного человека и предваряющих слов к речи другого человека.

Answer (score 3):

*Это «он отвечал», висящее на предыдущей строке, меня смущает.*

Если уж очень смущает, используйте "симбиоз" прямой и косвенной речи.
(Вопрос, переданный в косвенной речи, называется косвенным вопросом. *После косвенного вопроса **вопросительный знак не ставится***.)

Когда старца спрашивали, как дела, он отвечал:
— Слава Богу за всё!
— Богу-то слава, дела-то как? — спрашивали его снова.

***Дополнение*** (к комментарию)

В "большом"(законченном) сложноподчиненном предложении — прямая речь двух разных объектов. Ваше оформление второго варианта неправильно.

***" – Как дела? — он отвечал:"***
Фраза "Как дела?" принадлежит одному лицу, "он отвечал" — авторские слова для другого лица. Их в абзацном диалоге в одной строке совмещать нельзя.
Я вижу такой вариант (С изничтожением слова "когда"; возможно, с добавлением слова "часто". Если *"спрашивали"*, значит, спрашивали уже не единожды. Для одного раза больше бы подошло "когда его спросили".):

Старца [часто] спрашивали:
– Как дела?
Он отвечал:
— Слава Богу за всё!
— Богу-то слава, дела-то как? — спрашивали его снова.

Comment: А если текст авторский и прямую речь не удаётся перевести в косвенную? Можно ли оставить так, как я привёл во втором варианте?

Comment: В комментарии не получится объяснить все. Сейчас дам дополнение в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Когда старца спрашивали: «Как дела?», он отвечал: «Слава Богу за всё!»

Это не диалог, а сложноподчиненное предложение прямой речью, в котором и главная, и придаточная часть состоят из слов автора и прямой речи. Приведенный вами вариант записи "диалога в абзац" некорректен, так как такие предложения обычно записываются  в подбор.

Поэтому исходное предложение можно дополнить следующим образом: Когда старца спрашивали: «Как дела?», он отвечал: «Слава Богу за всё!» — "Богу-то слава, дела-то как?" — спрашивали его снова.

Другой вариант - использовать упрощенную запись прямой речи, и тогда возможно оформление "в абзац":

Когда старца спрашивали "Как дела?", он отвечал:

— Слава Богу за всё!

— Богу-то слава, дела-то как? — спрашивали его снова.

Если использовать запись: Когда старца спрашивали, как дела, он... - то выделительная способность косвенной речи намного меньше, вопроса практически не видно.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, чтобы удобно отредактировать текст, а в том, чтобы правильно расставить знаки препинания в этом вполне корректном тексте.

Comment: @Arina, у вас слово "когда " пропало и вместо одного предложения получилось два.

Comment: Спасибо, я теперь  стараюсь исправить  заданный текст.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: Когда старца спрашивали: «Как дела?» —  он отвечал: «Слава Богу за всё!»

Запятая и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам, но **объединенными общим авторским предложением:** Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», — «Да, недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно (Г.); если же в первой реплике имеются знаки **восклицательный или вопросительный, запятая опускается**: Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» — «Мне холодно», — ответил он; *то же при ином расположении частей авторского пред- ложения:*  **Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» — он ответил: «Мне холодно» (Ток.)**

См.: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)

**Дополнение**

В правилах пунтктуации отсутствуют рекомендации по оформлению примеров подобных вашему. 
Поэтому лучше оформить так, как предложила Арина.

**Когда старца спрашивали:«Как дела?», он отвечал: «Слава Богу за всё!» — "Богу-то слава, дела-то как?" — спрашивали его снова.**

Comment: Серж, после вопросительной прямой речи действительно рекомендуется ставить тире (хотя это правило часто нарушается), но ведь автор вопроса  просит рассмотреть полный вариант текста, а там и так этих тире хватает. Может быть, использовать упрощенный вариант прямой речи без двоеточия: Когда старца спрашивали «Как дела?», он....

Comment: Arina , ваш вариант тоже возможен. Поскольку в правлах пунктуации рассматриваемый вариант отсутствует. Дополню ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> Теперь представьте, что вопрос и ответ длиннее, или что дальше диалог
>   продолжается, и хочется записать фразы на отдельных строках,
>   начинающихся с тире. Как в таком случае правильно оформить пунктуацию?

Не стоит этого делать. Применительно к первой строке - точно не стоит. У вас прямая речь находится внутри придаточного. А "по строчкам" оформляется преимущественно диалоги, когда нет сомнений в структуре предложения, кто там чего и кому сказал. Подобное же вашей конструкции, с прямой речью, запрятанной глубоко внутри структуры, так оформлять нельзя, именно по подмеченной вами причине: путается источник и адресат речи. Я думаю, что корректным (хотя, возможно и не идеальным) будет оставить первую прямую речь в строчке, а дальше у же можно оформлять диалог по строкам, именно как диалог.

> **Когда старца спрашивали: "Как дела?", он отвечал:
>
>   — Слава Богу за всё!
>
>   — Богу-то слава, дела-то как? — спрашивали его снова.**

*Мне, признаться, даже двоеточии в первой строке перед кавычками хочется опустить, ибо считаю прямую речь в данном случае цитатой - членом предложения, но здесь об этом спорить не буду. В остальном считаю этот вариант вполне пригодным.*